# html force div to be 100% of the height of the parent and putting an image in its middle

Tags: html, css

I've searched and searched and tried different techniques with nothing that works.

I have 3 columns, and in the left and right columns I have an image that needs to be vertically aligned to the center as well as horizontally to the center. However, my middle content div stretches down a bit. So I would like my 2 columns to match the height. These 3 columns are wrapped in another div.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please give your code you tried and also a screenshot if possible !

Answer (score 1):

in your case it's better to use table instead of div because any change in some cell inside certain row will effect the other cells.. try this code it may do the job

```
<div style="border:1px black solid; width:850px; margin:auto">
  <table style="border:1px red solid; width:100%; height:500px; text-align:center" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="border:1px lime solid">1</td>
      <td style="border:1px lime solid">2</td>
      <td style="border:1px lime solid">3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using a table for layout (bad) instead use semantic markup (good) and CSS _tabular layout_, e.g. `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. Further: [you should not mix presentation with your markup](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wat you mean by "100% of the height", that shouldn't matter, but I would just play around with the css "margin" attribute, and assign percentages (not pixels) to it based on the parent size.  It may not be what you're looking for, but it's saved my butt on sites before, and it's probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
margin: auto;
padding: auto
```